# How to submit parent window form when child window closes

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview

I have a `gridview` displayed in a page which also has a link. When I click on the link, a `showModalDialog()` will open up where I can edit the value. 
After that when pressing Update button the value is getting updated in the database and my child form closes perfectly. 
But I need to update my parent page table as well. So that the new value gets reflected in the parent form. I tried the following in the child window.
`<body onunload="window.opener.document.forms[0].submit();">`
But that is not working. Suggest me a good solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have onUnload in a modal dialog

```
var res = showModalDialog(...); // execution is blocked until modal is closed
if (res) location.reload(1); // res contains what dialog set returnValue to
```

and in modal dialog you do

```
window.returnValue=true; // if ok submission
window.close(); // will return control to opening window
```

Anyway, did you look to the right? there are many duplicate questions about gridviews and modal dialogues

Comment: @mplugjan the problem is Firefox shows that the information resend or cancel dialogue box. I don't nee that. I need to update without any confirmation message.

Comment: That is due to a form having been posted to that page. If you replace the page that had the form result with a new page or use GET then you will not get that message. Alternatively do NOT reload the page but ajax in the contents

Comment: I uses this code. It works fine. var ReturnFromDialogue = window.showModalDialog('ShowRecord.aspx?Id=' + Id, '', "dialogWidth: 300; dialogHeight: 250");
            if (ReturnFromDialogue)
            {
                var btnSearch = document.getElementById("btnSearch");
                btnSearch.click();
            }

Comment: please add my code to yor answer. so that others can easily find out quickly.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have a function on Update button click, which updates the database and close the form, can you place that code (the one that you have in unload) in that function before closing the window